# How does a HCF4051BE multiplexer work, at a very simple level?

Tags: multiplexer

I'm a totally noob, so please, take this in consideration when replying :)

I want to understand how this multiplexer works. I tried to Google it, but all the answers was too advanced for me.

I mean, whats each pin is for? What happens when I send a sign to pin 'X'? What should I do to use it as a mux (or demux)?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! As written, your question is very broad. Please tell us what you _do_ understand. Do you know what a multiplexer is and how a digital multiplexer works? Do you understand how digital logic works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

If you want to know what it does for you (rather than how it works internally) you can visualize the chip as an eight-position rotary switch, COM OUT/In is the common contact, CHANNEL I/O the 8 individual contacts.

The position of the switch is determined by the digital value on the pins A-B-C. The INH input (when active) sets the switch to a 9th position that is not externally connected.

In practice the switch is not ideal: it has a non-connectible (and somehwat non-linear) series resistance, it can not handle voltages outside the Vee - Vdd range, etc.

Comment: Wow, this was accepted after 9 months :)